# CakePHP - best way to model a number of API calls

Tags: php, cakephp

I am busy on a project that involves calling the API's of nine other sites.  This number is expected to increase in the future and the actual method of API will differ (SOAP or XML).

There is a specification that each site needs to be modular so that my client will be able to sell them our API (which they can then give to other aggregators).

I've completed a number of Cake projects in the past but all of those were database driven.  Can somebody advise what the best way to approach this would be?

At the moment I am thinking of making each API a plugin.  I will place the API calls into a model (not attached to a database table) and then the rest will follow naturally.  Because the actual views of each API will differ I won't be able to use a common controller or views (each company API we consume has different business rules).

Can anybody tell me if this approach sounds reasonable or if I'm off track?

Thanks,
 Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in your root application you could extend AppModel. A SoapModel for Soap-based API calls and RestModel for REST-based calls, etc.

Then in each plug-in, you could make the model extend the appropriate class for the basic communication, and then you only have to handle the site-specific business rules in those models. This extra layer of abstraction would nicely hide away the WS implementation details.

You don't even necessarily need to split these into plugins if you're going the fat model route. Plugins are only particularly useful if you want to self-contain a "sub-application" of some kind and make it re-usable across other Cake applications.

Comment: Thanks for this.  The plugin approach is needed because of the requirement that the API's be able to be used by other developers.  I like the idea of creating an abstraction layer for common communications and probably parsing.